# How to "ask" an ActorSelection

Tags: scala, akka

How do I "ask" an actor that should be provided by its path?

```scala
ask(context.actorSelection("../foo"), GetInfoMessage)
```

…results in an `ActorSelection` but only `ActorRef`s can be "asked".
Alternatively, `context.actorFor` returns an `ActorRef`, but this function is deprecated according to the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html#What_is_the_Difference_Between_Actor_Reference_and_Path_).

Comment: we might want to offer `ask` also for ActorSelection, good point (https://www.assembla.com/spaces/ddEDvgVAKr3QrUeJe5aVNr/tickets/3261)

Comment: @RolandKuhn Yes, this would be very useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Later on that page you will see

> To acquire an ActorRef that is bound to the life-cycle of a specific actor you need to send a message, such as the built-in Identify message, to the actor and use the sender reference of a reply from the actor.

So it's a three step process.  Use `actorSelection`, then send `Identify`, then `ask`.

This is only for Akka 2.2 though, so in Akka 2.1 or prior you still need to use `actorFor`.

The rationale is explained in the [2.2 Migration Guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.1.x-2.2.x.html#Use_actorSelection_instead_of_actorFor).

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked this section. Unfortunately this means that it's currently not possible to get the `ActorRef` in a completely `Future` based way.

Answer (score 15):

Since Akka 2.2.1 you can use `ActorSelection.resolveOne` to get an `ActorRef` from a selection:

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.1/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSelection

Then you can ask the ActorRef as you normally do

Comment: Does this work if target actor is pooled? I mean, if I resolve one actor and send multiple messages to it, do I send to the pool each time or to the same actor?